# How to over ride a InputStream method read() to return a character?

Tags: java

The question was: Develop a class `ConvertToLowerCase` that derives from `FileInputStream` and overrides the `read()` method that is derived from `FileInputStream` such that overriding `read()` method returns a lower case character.  Use this class to convert the file information in `in.txt` to lowercase text and write it to the file `out.txt`.

The problem is that the program crashes in the middle and gives an error of unhandled heap, and it doesn't print the last word i.e. head in the `out.txt`

Here's the in.txt:

```
How High he holds His Haughty head
```

Here's the out.txt:

```
how high he holds his haughty
```

(notice the word head is missing)

I can't figure out the problem. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
//ConvertToLowerCase class
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
public class CovertToLowerCase extends FileInputStream { //inherits from FileInputStream

public CovertToLowerCase(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    super(name);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public int read() throws IOException {
    char c=(char) super.read(); //calling the super method read
    c=Character.toLowerCase(c);
    return c;   
}

}

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HW4ex2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    CovertToLowerCase c1=null;
    FileOutputStream output=null;

    try {


 c1= new CovertToLowerCase("C:/Users/user/workspace/HW4ex2/in.txt");
     output= new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/user/workspace/HW4ex2/out.txt");
        int a;
        while ((a=c1.read()) != -1)
        {
            System.out.print(a);
            output.write(a);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Kindly explain your teacher that inheriting from InputStream, which is used to read bytes, and not characters, is not the right way to solve this problem. A Reader is used to read characters. And the decorator pattern should be used. Depressing, really to see teachers give such stupid instructions.

Comment: I think there might be some EOF condition returned from read at some point and that won't be convertible to a lowercase character.

Comment: I am sorry, i just editted the code, its supposed to inherit from FileInputStream.

Comment: that comment is not helping me. I am not doing this by choice, it is what has been asked me to do. Thank you anyway, appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

OK. First of all, your main method prints ints, and not characters. So the following line

```
System.out.print(a);
```

should be

```
System.out.print((char) a);
```

Second, a stream signals that it has reached the end of the file by returning -1. But you always convert what you got to a char, without ever checking that the end has been reached. So the read method should be:

```
public int read() throws IOException {
    int i = super.read(); //calling the super method read
    if (i < 0) { // if EOF, signal it 
        return i;
    }
    return (Character.toLowerCase((char) i)); // otherwise, convert to char and return the lowercase
}
```